# Searchkick word_start not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

Searchkick autocomplete works perfectly with text_start, but word_start doesn't do what it's supposed to do regarding finding a word within a body of text.

Model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
      searchkick word_start: [:title, :description]
```

Controller:

```
def autocomplete
 book = Book.search(params[:term], fields: [{title: :word_start}, {description: :word_start}], limit: 10).map(&:title)
end
```

Am I missing something?

Here's the Script for autocomplete

```
<script>
 $("#query").autocomplete({
   source: "/searches/autocomplete",
   minLength: 2
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding word_start to model

```
def autocomplete
 book = Book.search(params[:term], limit: 10).map(&:title)
end
```

in controller, remove the fields